# How can I solve the error "ILLEGAL START OF AN EXPRESSION?

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Factors{

    protected int m;
    protected Vector myVector;
    protected int primeFactors;

    public Factors(int m) {
        myVector=new Vector();
        this.m=m;
        primeFactors=0;

        public Vector thefactors(){
            for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(m);i++) {
                if (m%i==0) {
                    myVector.add(i);

                }
                primeFactors=myVector.add(i);
            }
            return this.get(primeFactors);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            /*tests the methods implementation and 
            converts the command-line string arguments
            to integers */
            int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            Factors roy = new Factors(num);
            roy.thefactors();

    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a method inside a constructor -- not allowed. In the future, please improve your question as yours is just a broad statement of error and code, no indication where the error is located or any detail on what the code is supposed to do. A little more effort will make it easy for folks to help you -- please do this.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a method inside of a constructor -- not allowed.

```
 public Factors(int m) {
    myVector=new Vector();
    this.m=m;
    primeFactors=0;

    public Vector thefactors(){
```